# ! Use of \@x next doesn't match its definition, using memoir class, toc, chapter and begin{figure}

Tags: memoir, paths

I have issues compiling with using memoir class, table of contents, a chapter and begin{figure}.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[british, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{test}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{testing.pdf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If I remove either \tableofcontents, \chapter, or the begin{figure} it works fine.
I tried to run the code on my non-portable version on my PC, which had no troubles. 
I already reinstalled the portable-version but nothing changed.

```
! Use of \@xnext doesn't match its definition.
\@freelist ->,
              \bx@E ,,\bx@F ,,\bx@G ,,\bx@H ,,\bx@I ,,\bx@J ,,\bx@K ,,\bx@L ...
l.10 \includegraphics
                     [width=\textwidth]{testing.pdf}
?
```

So obvioulsy there must be something wrong with MiKteX since the code works with a different installation of it. I'm using MiKTeX version 2.9.7300.

While in the MiKTeX console I'm receiving this error for a PATH issue, despite the path variable being the same directory. Not sure tho if it has something to do with the original problem.

Any kind of advise or help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

that is a known bug https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/51 which will resolved when babel is updated is a few days

As a work-around:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[british, ngerman]{babel}
\makeatletter\AtBeginDocument{\let\@elt\relax}\makeatother
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{test}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the work-around resolves it

Comment: This error presented in the Ubuntu 20.10. Thank you for this work-around.

Comment: It's 2021, Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20, and the bug is still there...

Comment: @pawel_winzig the bug is long gone, so complain to ubuntu if their tex system is not up-to-date.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Can you suggest how to properly update it?

Comment: No, I'm on windows. But normally people who want an up-to-date system install a vanilla tex system and don't use the tex of the distribution.