# Error when inserting figure ! Use of \@xnext doesn't match its definition

Tags: floats, pdftex

I am trying to insert a figure in my latex document. This unfortunately gives me the error

```
! Use of \@xnext doesn't match its definition.
\@freelist ->,
              \bx@E ,,\bx@F ,,\bx@G ,,\bx@H ,,\bx@I ,,\bx@J ,,\bx@K ,,\bx@L ...
l.20   t
        estfigure
?
```

This is my reduced latex file

```
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%% test.tex -- main
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- 

\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[citeauthor]{basilea}


\title                  {title}
\thesistype         {thesis}

\department         {department}
\faculty                {Faculty }
\research           {research}

\examiner           {examiner}
\supervisor         {supervisor}

\authors            {authors}
\email                {email}
\immatriculnr       {matr}

\date                       {\today}

\ulogo              {example-image-a} 


\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
\thesisfront
\maketitle
\pagestyle{thesis}
\thesistoc
\thesismain
\begin{figure}
  
\end{figure}
\thesisappendix
\thesisbib
\thesisback
\end{document}
```

And the package 'basilea.sty', which is a template for theses from my university.

```
%%
%%  This file is originally based on 'ECSthesis.cls' by Steve R. Gunn
%%  and 'phdthesis.sty' by Jamie Stevens. In this new version many parts
%%  have been replaced by calls to the memoir package. Many existing
%%  templates using the memoir served as model.
%%
%%  v.2.0
%%
%%  2014, Ivan Giangreco
%%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{basilea}[2014]

\newcommand*{\basileaBibStyle}{thesis}

%%
%% Provides the option to use \citet to get the authors name
%% Internally, this changes the bibliographystyle from thesis to plainnat
%%
\DeclareOption{citeauthor}{
    \renewcommand*{\basileaBibStyle}{plainnat}
}
%%
%% Provides the default option to not use \citet to get the authors name
%% Internally, this sets the bibliographystyle to thesis
%%
\DeclareOption{citenumber}{
    \renewcommand*{\basileaBibStyle}{thesis}
}

\ExecuteOptions{citenumber}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
%\makeatletter\AtBeginDocument{\let\@elt\relax}\makeatother
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% text to be set for frontpage
\newcommand*{\supervisor}[1]{\def\supervisorint{#1}}
\newcommand*{\examiner}[1]{\def\examinerint{#1}}
\newcommand*{\authors}[1]{\def\authorsint{#1}}
\newcommand*{\email}[1]{\def\emailint{#1}}
\newcommand*{\ulogo}[1]{\def\universitylogoint{#1}}
\newcommand*{\department}[1]{\def\departmentint{#1}}
\newcommand*{\faculty}[1]{\def\facultyint{#1}}
\newcommand*{\research}[1]{\def\researchgroupint{#1}}
\newcommand*{\thesistype}[1]{\def\thesistypeint{#1}}
\newcommand*{\immatriculnr}[1]{\def\immatriculnrint{#1}}

\def\titleint{\@title}
\def\dateint{\@date}

% settings for nomenclature (i.e. the abbreviations)
% - for using in text use e.g. \nomenclature{LED}{Light-Emitting Diode}
% this will print the text directly as Light-Emitting Diode (LED)
% - the abbreviations for the whole document can be printed with the command \thesisnomencl
% - invoke MakeIndex to create a *.nlo file (see also documentation of nomenclature package)
\usepackage{nomencl}
\newcommand*{\nomenclint}{}
\let\nomenclint\nomenclature
\renewcommand*{\nomenclature}[2]{\textit{#2} (#1) \nomenclint{#1}{#2}}
\makenomenclature
\newcommand*{\thesisnomencl}{\renewcommand{\nomname}{\iflanguage{english}{Abbreviations}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}}\printnomenclature\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\iflanguage{english}{Abbreviations}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}}}

% graphics 
% (see also floats section in this document for more options)
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{everyshi}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\newsubfloat{figure}

% definition of fonts (phv is Helvetica, pcr is Courrier)
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
  
% definition of colors
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\definecolor{chaptercolor}{rgb}{.7,.7,.7}
\definecolor{emphasizecolor}{rgb}{.7,.7,.7}

% margins
\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{3.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{3.5cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

% document organization
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\newcounter{dummy}
\newcommand\addtotoc[1]{
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}

% definition of chapter style (i.e. large number and text)
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{50pt}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{1pt}
\newcommand*{\colorchapnumber}{\color{chaptercolor}}
\newcommand*{\fontchapnumber}{\usefont{T1}{phv}{b}{n}\fontsize{100}{130}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\fontchaptitle}{\sffamily\bfseries\huge}
\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
\setlength{\midchapskip}{20mm}
\renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\raggedleft{\colorchapnumber\fontchapnumber\thechapter}\par}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\raggedleft\fontchaptitle{#1}\par \vspace{30pt} \nobreak}

% definition of (subsub)section styles
\setsecheadstyle{\sffamily\Large}
\setbeforesecskip{25pt}
\setaftersecskip{1pt}

\setsubsecheadstyle{\sffamily\large}
\setbeforesubsecskip{20pt}
\setaftersubsecskip{1pt}

\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\sffamily\normalsize}
\setbeforesubsubsecskip{20pt}
\setaftersubsubsecskip{1pt}

% definition of line spacing, indent of paragraph, etc.
\OnehalfSpacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\raggedbottom

% header, footer
\nouppercaseheads
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}

\makepagestyle{thesis}
\makeevenhead{thesis}{\leftmark}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddhead{thesis}{\leftmark}{}{\thepage}
\makeheadrule{thesis}{\textwidth}{0.2pt}
\makeevenfoot{thesis}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{thesis}{}{}{}
\copypagestyle{chapter}{empty}

% footnotes
\setlength{\skip\footins}{20pt}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{10pt}
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

% add highlighting possibilities
% use \hlt to highlight parts of text, e.g. \hlt{this is important}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\hlt}[1]{\hl{#1}}

% various imports
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm}

% clearing pages
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\newcommand*{\tmpcleardoublepage}{}
\let\tmpcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage

% floats
\captionstyle{\raggedright}
\setfloatlocations{figure}{ht!}
\setlength{\intextsep}{10pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt}

% definition of table of contents (i.e. title, header text, appearance in pdf-TOC, etc.)
\newcommand*{\thesistoc}{\cleardoublepage\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{\iflanguage{english}{Table of Contents}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}} \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\iflanguage{english}{Table of Contents}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}} \currentpdfbookmark{\iflanguage{english}{Table of Contents}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}}{toc} \tableofcontents*}
% adds the word "Appendix" in front of chapters in the appendix section
\renewcommand*{\cftappendixname}{\iflanguage{english}{Appendix}{Anhang}\space}

% definition of bibliography
\newcommand*{\thesisbib}{\cleardoublepage\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{\iflanguage{english}{Bibliography}{Literaturverzeichnis}} \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\iflanguage{english}{Bibliography}{Literaturverzeichnis}}\bibliographystyle{\basileaBibStyle}\bibliography{thesis}}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}

% document structure
\newcommand*{\thesisfront}{\frontmatter \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage }
\newcommand*{\thesismain}{ \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}} \mainmatter \let\cleardoublepage\tmpcleardoublepage }
\newcommand*{\thesisappendix}{ \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}} \appendix \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage}

\newcommand*{\thesisback}{ \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}} \backmatter \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage}

% title page
\renewcommand\maketitle{
  \hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}
  \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorsint}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  {\raggedright\includegraphics{\universitylogoint}}\par
    \begin{center}
      \vspace{3cm}
      {\Huge \sffamily \bfseries \@title \par}
      \vspace{0.5cm}
      {\thesistypeint \par}
      \vspace{3cm}    
      {\facultyint \par}
      {\departmentint \par}
      {\researchgroupint \par}
      \vspace{1.5cm}
      {\iflanguage{english}{Examiner}{Beurteiler}: \examinerint \par}
      {\iflanguage{english}{Supervisor}{Zweitbeurteiler}: \supervisorint \par}
      \vspace{1.5cm}
      {\authorsint \par}
      {\emailint \par}
      {\immatriculnrint \par}      
      \vfill
      {\@date \par}
   \end{center}
}

% declaration
\newcommand{\formlabel}[2]{\vspace{0.25cm}\textbf{\sffamily \footnotesize #1 --- #2}\\}

% urls
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

% footnotes
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

% math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

% reference settings
\usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
   bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,hypertexnames=false,
   colorlinks,linkcolor={black},citecolor={black},urlcolor={black}, filecolor={black},
   pdfstartview={FitV}, breaklinks=true, unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
% rename here, e.g. \crefname{listing}{Algorithm}{Algorithm}  



% todos
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos, textwidth=4cm]{todonotes} % add ",disable" in [] to remove all todos, missing figures and the todo list
\newcommand{\todoEmpty}[2][]{\todo[fancyline, #1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\todoMissing}[2][]{\todoEmpty[color=magenta!80, linecolor=magenta!80, #1]{Missing: #2}}
\newcommand{\todoCheck}[2][]{\todoEmpty[color=red!80, linecolor=red!80, #1]{Check: #2}}
\newcommand{\todoRevise}[2][]{\todoEmpty[color=orange!80, linecolor=orange!80, #1]{Revise: #2}}
\newcommand{\todoCitation}[2][]{\todoEmpty[color=yellow!80, linecolor=yellow!80, #1]{Citation: #2}}
\newcommand{\todoLanguage}[2][]{\todoEmpty[color=blue!40!white, linecolor=blue!40!white, #1]{Language: #2}}
\newcommand{\todoQuestion}[2][]{\todoEmpty[color=green!80!white, linecolor=green!80!white, #1]{Question: #2}}
\newcommand{\todoNote}[2][]{\todoEmpty[color=black!20!white, linecolor=black!20!white, #1]{Note: #2}}
\newcommand{\todoFigure}[5]{\begin{figure}[#1]\centering\missingfigure[figwidth=#2]{#3}\caption{#4}\label{#5}\end{figure}}

\endinput

%% End of file 'basilea.sty'
```

I already found other issues with a similar problem like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530439/use-of-x-next-doesnt-match-its-definition-using-memoir-class-toc-chapter) but the workaround mentioned will give me the following error message:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1phv.fd)
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
\@->\spacefactor
                 \@m {}
l.34 \pagestyle
               {thesis}
?
```

I am on WSL2 Ubuntu version Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and I have updated all my packages including texlive.
pdflatex version:

```
pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
Copyright 2019 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.01
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please copy the code that you included above, into a new directory and try to compile it. You will notice that your example is not complete. E.g., you use package `basilea_test`, but provide `basilea,sty`. Moreover, you input `Template/custom_commands.tex` but don't provide it. If I remove this statement and assume basilea=basilea_test, I get an error, but it is different  from yours. Please make sure that the example posted here shows the same error that you see.

Comment: @gernot Thanks for your reply. You're right, I tried to reduce the file as much as possible but I ended up with more errors. And then I pasted the wrong file here. I have updated the test.tex file, I would be thankful if you could take a look at it again.

Comment: I tried your sample code with TeXlive 2020, and it compiles without errors. I don't think that the problem is your version of `pdflatex`, but rather some outdated package. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530439/use-of-x-next-doesnt-match-its-definition-using-memoir-class-toc-chapter which might be related.

Comment: @gernot How do I update packages? I have tried to update with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` do I have to do anything else to update them on linux?

Comment: The native texlive packages of Ubuntu (or other Linux distributions) are always outdated and may lag behind a year. Install TeXlive independently of Ubuntu, following the instructions at https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: I saved basilea.sty and the reduced LaTeX file on my system and compiled the reduced LaTeX file. I didn't get any error-message.I suppose the issue is with some outdated package whose bugs were fixed in the meantime. The error ```! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode. \@->\spacefactor \@m {}``` comes from @ not being letter where it should be letter: In basilea.sty I find: `%\makeatletter\AtBeginDocument{\let\@elt\relax}\makeatother`. Don't do `\makeatletter..\makeatother` in .sty-files! In .sty-files @ is letter by default. Don't switch @ to "other" via `\makeatother` in .sty-files!

Comment: In the answer linked by you ```\AtBeginDocument{\let\@elt\relax}``` is nested between `\makeatletter`..`\makeatother` because in that answer those things don't occur in a .sty-file (where due to actions triggered by `\usepackage` @ would be "letter", i.e., category code 11, by default) but occur in a .tex-file where @ is "other", i.e., category code 12,  by default.

Comment: Thanks @UlrichDiez and gernot. I fixed it by manually installing the newest version of latex